# Bootstrap align-middle class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I kinda feel stupid here asking this, but I can't seem to get this text to align middle with the button using bootstraps's `align-middle` class

```
<span class="align-middle">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm align-middle mt-3">
        <span class="fa fa-plus nr-2"></span>
    </button>
    <small>Add new website</small>
</span>
```

I have also tried...

```
<span class="align-middle">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm align-middle mt-3">
        <span class="fa fa-plus nr-2"></span>
    </button>
    <small class="align-middle">Add new website</small>
</span>
```

Comment: Are you trying to vertically center text ?

Comment: yes trying to vertically center

Answer (score 0):

To vertically center-align the text to the button you can do this:

1. Add the `d-flex` class to the parent element (`col` in this case but could also be another `div` inside the container)
2. Add the `align-self-center` class to the text element.

An easier way would be to move the top margin (`mt-3`) to a parent element.

Here are both for comparison (Click the "run code snippet" button below):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col d-flex">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm fa fa-plus mr-2 mt-3" style="height: 80px"></button>
            <small class="align-self-center">Add new website</small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm fa fa-plus mr-2" style="height: 80px"></button>
            <small>Add new website</small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: I added `style="height: 80px"` to make things clearer in regards to alignment.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the top margin `mt-3`... it's throwing off the vertical alignment.

```
<span class="align-middle">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
            <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
        </button>
        <small>Add new website</small>
</span>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/3lA1M96Na1